# Error in linq statement

Tags: c#, linq

I am getting error for following LINQ statement

**Error**

> "Can't convert implicitly type bool to string

```
string UserId = Context.Users.Where(x => x.UserName == username).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id);
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: This is just C#, it is not a linq expression.

Comment: To be exact this is a lambda expression. But technically, LINQ and lambda producing the same results.

Comment: What type is `username`?

Comment: Your FirstOrDefault() is looking for a boolean comparison.

Comment: You have to pass a boolean expression to `FirstOrDefault`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want only id like this

```
string UserId = Context.Users.Where(x => x.UserName == username).Select(g=> g.Id.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
```

If you want users object like this

```
   var Usersobj=Context.Users.Where(x => x.UserName == username).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Keep in mind that your first code will now throw a null reference exception when there is no matching item in the sequence. Therefore, you should use `First()` to have an exception that tells you there was no matching item.

Comment: @Mukesh Kalgude, whats happening here "FirstOrDefault().id.ToString();" explain plz.. how it make difference from my statement ".FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id);"

Comment: @immirza firstorDefault : Returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if the sequence contains no elements. Not any overloaded method to passing value. More concept to refer this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @immirza First comment also read. If your concept clear then given right marks of answer.

Comment: @Mukesh Kalgude, just upvoted ur answer and it makes me clear. thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to check whether a user exists with the provided username, otherwise it will throw a null reference exception;

```
string id = string.Empty;
User user = Context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == username);
if(user != null)
{
    id=user.Id.ToString(); //if id is already a string no need for ToString()
}
```

or single line with c# 6;

```
string userId = Context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == username)?.Id.ToString();
```

Comment: syntax error with string userId = Context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == username)?.Id.ToString();

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
string UserId = Context.Users.Where(x => x.UserName == username).Select(s => s.Id).DefaultIfEmpty(String.Empty).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

x=>x.Id is used for enumerating over the collection and applying the condition to check which one matches and then returns the first match.
`FirstOrDefault<Tsource>` if `<Tsource>` is empty the first element in source.
Here FirstOrDefault taken only by passing the id, so use x=>x.Id==id

```
var user =  Context.Users.Where(x => x.UserName == Username ).FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id==id)
```

or

```
string UserId = Context.Users.Where(x => x.UserName == Username ).FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id==id).ToString();
```